# Angular4 - custom pipe creation

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I cant understand one thing in the code below - why `(limit)` is in parenthesis?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe ({
 name: 'summary'
})

export class SummaryPipe implements PipeTransofm {
 transform(value: string, limit?: number) {
  if (!value) 
   return null;

  let specificLimit = (limit) ? limit : 50;
  return value.substr(0, specificLimit);
 }
}
```

Thanks

Here a screenshot, to be sure I copied it right:

[image]

Comment: are you sure you copied that part `(limit) ? : 50;` correctly? it seems to be an incorrect syntax

Comment: @Maximus, I am sure, I added a screenshot from the video of the Tutorial, from Udemy.com - https://www.udemy.com/angular-2-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: yeah, that's a different case, it is now correct syntax. the parenthesis are just a style preference, they make more sense for me when there's an expression inside like `(limit === 3) ? limit : 50`

Comment: @Maximus, Ok, thanks. Now I understand it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will throw syntax error because the true condition lacks an expression. The parenthesis are not needed in your example, you could write it like

```
let specificLimit = limit ? : 50;
```

too but like I said this will throw an error. You must give it a value for when the ternary yields true so something like:

```
let specificLimit = limit ? limit : 50;
```